# How To Dispatch Queued Jobs In Laravel On Shared Hosting (CPanel)

Tags: php, laravel, queue, cpanel, jobs

Good day all. I have this persisting problem with a laravel app I created. I want to send bulk emails to subscribers. I want to queue the emails (jobs)so that they won't slow down my app. I am using a shared hosting account. Without the queue process, the mails work work fine. However, without it, they do not work.
I am using database as Queue Connection and I have the "jobs" table set up in my database. I guess up till this point, everything is working perfectly well because anytime I send the mails, I can see the jobs in the database. The problem is that I can't seem to make the queue:work command on the shared hosting unlike on my system (locally).

Furthermore, I created command using `php artisan make:command cronEmail`, and inside App/Console/Kernel.php, I set up the **schedule method** as follows

```php
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('queue:work --tries=3')
            ->cron('* * * * * *')
            ->withoutOverlapping();
}
```

I then created a cron job on my cpanel as follows:

`php /home/myrootfolder/mywebsitefolder/artisan queue:work >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Yet, still I don't get any result. The mails are not getting sent.

My Website files are set up as follows:
Inside the root folder of the cpanel, I created a new folder called "**mywebsitefolder**" where I put all my laravel files except for the "public folder". The contents of the public folder are placed inside the root folder's "public_html". I then edited my index.php accordingly. It's shown below:

```php
require __DIR__.'/../mywebsitefolder/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../mywebsitefolder/bootstrap/app.php';
```

So, could it be that I am not pointing to my "artisan" correctly or I am getting everything completely wrong?
Please, if anyone knows a better way of doing this or where I am getting it all wrong, I'll be glad. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you try to call your command instead? `php /home/myrootfolder/mywebsitefolder/artisan cronEmail >> /dev/null 2>&1` Your share hosting allow ssh connections ?

Answer (score 4):

You can easily from your `Cpanel` you will find terminal open it and run this command

```
nohup php artisan queue:work --daemon &
```

you can find the `terminal` in the advanced section

[image]

it will run your `queue` in the background

> make sure when you run the command above to be in your project **app** path

Comment: Thanks. My hosting does not have a terminal

Comment: @Korlahwarleh if your `cpanel` support `SSH` you can run the same command to from `SSH`

Comment: Thanks @Joseph. It is a shared hosting, and there is no root access.

Comment: Thank you so much. I saved my lot of time and only money because for this only I was about to migrate to VPS. Adding some point, to see running processes use command: ps x. Here you will get all the running process with job id. To kill the process: kill [job-id]